# Using NextJS <Link requires double tapping on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

When using the NextJS <Link tag, on mobile I have to double-tap in order for the link to route.

Here is the code:

```
<Link
     href="/methodology"
     passHref={true}
     target="_blank"
     rel="noopener noreferrer"
     className="w-auto text-right text-sm text-riskfactor-400 underline underline-offset-2 hover:text-riskfactor-300 md:w-[345px]"
     onClick={() =>
        handleLinkAnalytics(
          'How is Flood Calculated?',
          '/methodology',
        )
     }
    >
    How is Flood Calculated?
</Link>
```

I passed in `passHref` but that didn't seem to solve the issue

Comment: there is a closed [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43972) in the `nextJs` *GitHub repo*, Could you please look into this issue? It seems like a lot of people are experiencing it. I think it might be related to the `nextJs` version.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be related to a touch event delay on mobile devices. You can try using the `fastclick` library to eliminate the 300ms delay on click events in mobile browsers.

The code is following.

```
import React from 'react';
import fastclick from 'fastclick';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fastclick.attach(document.body);
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```